Not able to import functions from python file
Folder structure:

I have a master script which calls requires.py only. The requires.py file is responsible to call all the necessary supporting files which are in the folder essentials.
Snippet of requires.py:
import os
import sys
import time
from pathlib import *

global formatter 
formatter = "\n #################### =>  "


wokring_dir = os.getcwd()
essential_path = "\essentials"
#forimport = os.path.join(wokring_dir,essential_path)
forimport = (wokring_dir)+essential_path
os.chdir(forimport)
print(formatter,os.getcwd())

from selectthis import printthis
printthis()

Here I am not able to import anything from selectthis. Why is that?

Python doesn't care about the current working directory when importing. Try from essentials.selectthis import printthis.

In master_script.py just import requires and in requires.py just from essentials.selectthis import printthis(). Note that importing requires will immediately execute the module, and since you have all the code in the main body of the module, it will all execute immediately when imported. If you need it to run at a specific time, just wrap it all in a function and import that.

It worked! . Writing it as answer

As said by @Michael and @Grismar ,
<package_name>.filename import *
in my case
from essentials.selectthis import *

